# screen_util.dart:58:5: Error: 'FlutterWindow' isn't a type. FlutterWindow? window,

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

:/Users/afaqz/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_screenutil-5.6.0/lib/src/screen_util.dart:58:5: Error: Type 'FlutterWindow' not found.
FlutterWindow? window,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/afaqz/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_screenutil-5.6.0/lib/src/screen_util.dart:58:5: Error: 'FlutterWindow' isn't a type.
FlutterWindow? window,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^ show this massage when i upgrade the flutter dont know what to do?

i try alot but how to fix this problen no find any where

Comment: Is your emulator selected for running your flutter project?

Answer (score 3):

Was facing the same issue. Running `flutter pub upgrade` and `flutter pub outdated` in the terminal in the root folder of the project worked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your flutter_screenutil, try to update to newest version(flutter_screenutil: ^5.8.3)

Then delete packages

```
flutter pub clean
```

Get packages

```
flutter pub get
```

Maybe you should restart vs code too